# Snowflake - error converting binary to geography

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, wkb, dbgeography

I am running the following query:

`select ST_GEOGRAPHYFROMWKB('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');`

but I get the error message:
Error parsing WKB input: Type '16777231' unknown.

I cannot find information that can lead me to solve this issue. Has anyone ever faced it?

Answer (score 1):

Your WKB value doesn't look correct. The first byte indicates the byte order for the data:

00 : big endian

01 : little endian

Yours starts with 11.

For more information, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary)